# Switching from svg to canvas on d3 force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, canvas

Basically i'm trying to migrate from svg to canvas based graph to improve fps on large datasets.

I've been using d3 (v3) force layout to represent a network of nodes and links and i noticed a decay of performance as the number of svg elements on screen increased. To prevent this i started looking at canvas as a possible alternative and i saw some interesting results on the web. I completely converted my code to draw the same stuff on canvas instead of svg while maintaining the d3 force layout characteristics.

```
this._mainCanvas = d3.select(this._container).append('canvas')
  .attr('width', this._width)
  .attr('height', this._height);

this._mainContext = this._mainCanvas.node().getContext('2d');

this._simulation = d3.layout
  .force()
  .size([this._width, this._height])
  .gravity(0.35)
  .charge(-2000)
  .theta(0.85)
  .alpha(0.05)
  .friction(0.7)
  .nodes(this.data.nodes)
  .links(this.data.relationships)
  .linkDistance(1000)
  .linkStrength(this._linkStrength)
  .on('tick', self._tick())
  .start();

this._tick() {
    this._mainContext.clearRect(0, 0, this._width, this._height);

    // draw links
    this.data.relationships.forEach(function (d) {
      self._mainContext.strokeStyle = 'rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5)';
      self._mainContext.beginPath();
      self._mainContext.moveTo(d.source.x, d.source.y);
      self._mainContext.lineTo(d.target.x, d.target.y);
      self._mainContext.lineWidth = d.linkWeight;
      self._mainContext.stroke();
    });

    this.data.nodes.forEach(function (d) {
      // Node
      self._mainContext.fillStyle = d.color;
      self._mainContext.beginPath();
      self._mainContext.moveTo(d.x, d.y);
      self._mainContext.arc(d.x, d.y, d.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      self._mainContext.strokeStyle = d3.rgb(d.color).darker(1);
      self._mainContext.lineWidth = 2;
      self._mainContext.stroke();
      self._mainContext.fill();
      self._mainContext.closePath();
      // Text
      self._mainContext.font = parseInt(Math.round(d.radius * 0.75)) + 'px' + ' Open Sans';
      self._mainContext.textBaseline = 'middle';
      self._mainContext.textAlign = 'start';
      self._mainContext.fillStyle = 'black';
      self._mainContext.fillText(d.value, d.x + parseInt(Math.round(d.radius * 1.25)), d.y);
      // Icon
      self._mainContext.font = parseInt(Math.round(d.radius * 0.75)) + 'px' + ' FontAwesome';
      self._mainContext.textBaseline = 'middle';
      self._mainContext.textAlign = 'center';
      self._mainContext.fillStyle = 'white';
      self._mainContext.fillText(d.icon, d.x, d.y);

    });
}
```

The final result has been quite disappointing, performance didnt improve by a single bit instead of what i was expecting reading on the web and testing various examples. So i'm wondering, what am i doing wrong? Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Some of the examples i'm referring to are the following ones

- https://bl.ocks.org/tafsiri/b83f60f23bf4ce130ca2 (svg)
- https://bl.ocks.org/tafsiri/e9016e1b8d36bae56572 (canvas)
- https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3180395 (d3 force layout on canvas)

Comment: How many nodes are we talking about? Most likely the performance is affected by the workings of the force simulation itself rather than by manipulating the DOM. Hence, there is not much of a gain by switching over to canvas. Can you set up a [mcve]?

Comment: Ok, i set up an example on jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/7b64azm9/1/) and i found out what i was doing wrong with my live version of it: i have some functions that calculate the link weight and node radius between a range of predefined values, max and min, thanks to d3.scale.linear().domain(...).range(...) and apparently that's what is slowing me down. I have to figure out a way to do without...